# How can I return new IDs in accordance with a date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following data (merely an example, actual table has 600,000 rows) (aid = access id [primary key] and id = user id [foreign key]):

```
aid  |  id  |  date
332  |  1   |  2016-12-15
331  |  4   |  2016-12-15
330  |  3   |  2016-12-15
329  |  1   |  2016-12-14
328  |  1   |  2016-12-14
327  |  2   |  2016-12-14
326  |  3   |  2016-12-13
325  |  2   |  2016-12-13
324  |  1   |  2016-12-13
323  |  1   |  2016-12-12
322  |  3   |  2016-12-12
321  |  1   |  2016-12-12
```

Each id is a users primary key, and every time they access something in my system I log them in this table (with the date in the format as shown, and their id). A user can be logged multiple times a day.

I'm looking to: return the total number of times the thing has been accessed in a day and return the total number of NEW users who have accessed the thing in a day, for the last 8 days (something will always be logged each day, so using "LIMIT 8" is fine for getting only the last 8 days).

My SQL currently looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), COUNT(distinct id), date
FROM table
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 8;
```

That SQL does the first part correctly, but I can't figure out how to get it to return the number of users who have never accessed the thing until that day.

Desired results would be, the one "newuser" represents the user with id "4" as they have never accessed the thing before:

```
COUNT(id)  |  newusers  |  date
3          |  1         |  2016-12-15
3          |  0         |  2016-12-14
3          |  0         |  2016-12-13
3          |  0         |  2016-12-12
```

Sorry if I didn't explain this clear enough.

Comment: Then it should show `2` for `12-12-2016` and `1` for `13-12-2016` since they are accessing for the first time, right?

Comment: (Unless date is really datetime) you have no PRIMARY KEY, which may prove problematic in due course.

Comment: Users 1, 2 and 3 have all accessed BEFORE 12-12-2016 though.

Comment: Sorry man... I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Strawberry, there is a primary key, and about 10 other columns, I didn't include them as I didn't think they would help and just add irrelevant clutter to the question (more so than there already is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get new users you want the first day an id appeared:

```
select id, min(date)
from t
group by id;
```

The rest is just a `join` and `group by`:

```
select d.date, cnt, count(dd.id) as newusers
from (select date, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by date
     ) d left join
     (select id, min(date) as mindate
      from t
      group by id   
     ) dd  
     on d.date = dd.mindate
group by d.date, d.cnt
limit 8;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I think you meant "group by" instead of "order by" in the second last line -- by changing it to such this works amazingly.

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of new users you need to compare them to a set of ids over the past 8 days

My MySQL is a bit rusty, so you might have to correct the syntax.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id
    FROM table
    WHERE date BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 DAY)) AND DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
)
```

I'll leave it as a task for you to combine it with your other query ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hi if your date column in database is datetime/date or other date representing format you can do something like this:

for getting all users who accessed something in 8 days:

```
Select id, date from table 
where date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -9 DAY) AND NOW()
```

I think, you can do whatever grouping you want on that.
To get new users, you can either go with self join or with sub select

selfjoin:

```
select t.id, t.date from table as t
LEFT join table as t2 
   ON t.id = t2.id 
   AND t.date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AND NOW() 
   AND t2.date NOT BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -9 DAY) AND NOW()
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

i used left join to match all access from users and then in where excluded those rows. However self joins are slow, and even slower with LEFT join

subselect:

```
select id, date from table 
where date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AND NOW() 
AND id NOT IN ( 
   SELECT id FROM table 
   WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) 
)
```

I know those betweens with date_adds are not exactly nice looking, but i hope it will help you more than grouping dates

I would suggest using date with time for more information, but its entirely up to meaning of yours data